# How to get the index of elements in a matrix that match values of a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I would like to find the index of the elements in a matrix `m` that match with a vector `v1` and `v2`. So from something similar to `res` I would like to get element `2` and from
`res1` get 8. Thank you!

```
flink = c("logit", "probit", "GEVmodNS", "GEVmod")
fcor = c("tanimoto", "exponential", "gaussian", "independent")
v1 = c('logit', 'exponential')
v2 = c('probit', 'independent')
m = expand.grid(fcor,flink)
res = m %in%v1
res1 = m %in%v2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function in base R to do this -

```
match_a_row <- function(data, var1, var2) {
  which(data[[1]] == var1 & data[[2]] == var2)
}

match_a_row(m, 'exponential', 'logit')
#[1] 2
match_a_row(m, 'independent', 'probit')
#[1] 8
```

Answer (score 3):

```
which(apply(m, 1, function(x) all(x %in% v1)))
[1] 2

which(apply(m, 1, function(x) all(x %in% v2)))
[1] 8
```

If order matters so that you want a row to match the order of `v1` or `v2` exactly then use `==` instead of `%in%`.

Comment: I think `%in%` ignores the ordering, so either `v1 <- c('logit', 'exponential')` or `v1 <- c('exponential', logit')` would match the row `"logit" | "exponential"`.  Perhaps `==` would be better, as it ensures an actual *match* rather than a mere overlap of values.

Comment: @Greg this is a good point to make, but I used `%in%` based on the OP expected output, which is checking for containment rather than order.

Comment: I think OP is checking for order too, but they made a typo in their example.  I think it *should* be  `expand.grid(flink, fcor)`.

Comment: Hard to say, will wait for the OP to weigh in then.

Answer (score 2):

**UPdate:** Thanks to @Greg pointer!
We still could use `which` with `==` but have to declare the positions of the the vector and matrix elements:

```
> which(m[,1] == v1[2] & m[,2] == v1[1])
[1] 2
> which(m[,1] == v2[2] & m[,2] == v2[1])
[1] 8
```

**First answer**(which is not correct in the sense of OP's question)

```
which(v1 == m)
which(v2 == m)
```

```
> which(v1 == m)
[1]  2  6 10 14 17 19
> which(v2 == m)
[1]  4  8 12 16 21 23
```

Comment: I think OP is using `c('logit', 'exponential')` to represent a row of the matrix generated by `expand.grid()`; and they want to find the index of the matching row in `m`.

Comment: Ah. I see. Thanks Greg!

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
> which(!lengths(Map(setdiff, list(v1), asplit(m, 1))))
[1] 2

> which(!lengths(Map(setdiff, list(v2), asplit(m, 1))))
[1] 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want **order to matter** when matching

```
          Var2           Var1
   1     logit       tanimoto
   2     logit    exponential
#         ...           ...

# Should match row 2.
v1 <- c('logit', 'exponential')

# Should NOT match row 2.
v3 <- c('exponential', 'logit')
```

here's an elegant alternative with the native pipe [`|>`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pipeOp.html) that works for an **arbitrary number of fields**:

```
(v1 == t(m)) |> apply(2, all) |> which()
# [1] 2

(v2 == t(m)) |> apply(2, all) |> which()
# [1] 8
```

Just make sure you name your columns in the proper order

```
m <- expand.grid(flink, fcor)
```

such that they correspond to the values in `v1`, etc.

Comment: Nice way to use native pipe+1

Comment: @TarJae Thanks!  It's such a relief they *finally* introduced it into **`base`** R.  While one can certainly qualify functions like `dplyr::mutate()`, one can't do the same to a pipe operator in midstream: ```df  dplyr::`%>%`  dplyr::mutate(...)```!  When writing fully qualified code, I was often in the position of doing something like ```... `%:%` <- dplyr::`%>%` ...```, followed by something like `df %:% dplyr::mutate(...)`.